# How can I compare the lens serial number from the EXIF of a picture, to the serial on my lens?

Tags: lens, canon, serial-number

I have a Canon EOS 85mm f/1.2 L II lens. I sold it to someone, they claim it was broken and sent it back. I am trying to prove that the lens I sent to them, is not the one they returned.

From http://regex.info/exif.cgi

```
Lens Info   85mm f/?
Lens Model  EF85mm f/1.2L II USM
Lens Serial Number  0000020f30
```

My lens has a six digit number XXXXXX. How can I convert 0000020f30 or extract to get the 6 digit serial number?

Comment: Alternately, as long as you shipped it insured, you could just file a claim with the shipping company and let them sort it out.  If you find out it is in fact not the same lens, then that will stop being an option.

Comment: The buyer never said that there was damage from the shipping. I included a filter with the sale as a good will. That filter mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: 'Inquiring minds want to know': Was the serial number 134960?

Comment: No it was not. Started with a 22 actually. Downloading Canon's DPP to further compare.

Comment: @Zlatty - right, but if you shipped it intact and it arrived damaged, then assuming no fraud, the situation would be that it must have been damaged in shipping.  But now that you know it is fraud on the part of the recipient you have to deal with the mess rather than the shipper.  Hopefully you can make a strong enough case to avoid whoever you did the sale through from giving them their money back.

Comment: Right on its been a rough couple of weeks dealing with this.

Comment: The Jeffrey's EXIF Viewer may be returning the corect hex value of the lens, depending on which Canon camera body model the photo in question was used to take the photo. Newer models such as the 1D X and the 5D Mark III do report lens serial number in the EXIF information. Older models don't.

Comment: I always take a photo of stuff that I sell. I know I'm paranoid, but now at least I know that I'm also being chased :-).

Comment: An update: Was forced to pay 50% refund on the damaged lens. Need to shell out the money to Amazon, and then send off the lens to Canon for repairs. Lesson Learned: Document, photography, NEVER sell on Amazon Marketplace. Thanks on the help y'all!

Comment: @Zlatty - if they sent back a different lens than you sent them (by serial number) I would try pressing legal charges.  Contact the police and get a lawyer to go after Amazon for you.  Also see about going after the insurance on the shipping if Amazon says they believe it to be the same lens.  Get the shipping company to fight Amazon on it if you can.  If you didn't ship insured, then you are pretty much out of luck though.

Comment: Could you not attach the lens to your camera, take a picture then compare the serial numbers in the EXIF

Comment: Just as a thought - the serial number wasn't on the paperwork when you bought it, was it?  I noticed on my paperwork from when I last properly splashed out on a lens that it was recorded there.

Comment: You could also check the date code to see if they are different.

Comment: @James - No serial on the paperwork, maybe there was one on the invoice in the packing but as I do a lot of purchases with Amazon I just tossed it. :(

Answer (score 13):

I tried the Jeffrey's EXIF viewer with three images taken with the same camera (a Canon 50D) and three different lenses. **The 'Internal Serial Number' value returned by [Jeffrey's EXIF Viewer](http://regex.info/exif.cgi) was the same value for all three images taken with the same camera and three different lenses.** Each image was taken with, respectively, a Tamron SP AP 17-50mm f/2.8 XR Di-II, an EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II, and an EF 28-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS. The two Canon lenses were correctly identified in the "Lens Model" field (The Tamron was identified as a "Canon EF 28-70mm f/2.8L or Sigma or Tamron Lens" because many Tamron and Sigma lenses are known to spoof the lens ID for the older EF 28-70mm f/2.8L). This leads me to believe the "Internal Serial Number" value is a reference to the camera body, not the lens (at least on older Canon bodies that do not differentiate between two different copies of the same lens model for various purposes such as AFMA). Even though the the lens ID immediately precedes the "Internal Serial Number" value, it may not accurately reflect the serial number of the lens used to create the image. Images taken with my 7D using two different lenses shared the same "Internal Serial Number" with each other, a different number than the three images taken with three lenses using the 50D shared. Images taken with my 5D mark II have a blank "Internal Serial Number" value when using Jeffrey's EXIF Viewer.

Many Canon camera bodies have a separate internal serial number that doesn't match the one stamped on the exterior of the camera, at least not when the number in the EXIF is translated using a standard hex to decimal converter. This may also be the case regarding lens ID numbers with bodies that can differentiate between two different copies of the same model lens.

The value for 'Camera Serial Number' in the EXIF maker notes of images taken with my Canon 50D is 5AA411141. Using a standard converter yields a decimal value of 24331227457. Yet the Serial number stamped on the camera body is 1520708485. This number is correctly reported by *Digital Photo Professional* as the camera's serial number. Irfanview reports the serial number as "1520708485 (5AA411141)". Hmmm. The HEX number that correlates to the stamped serial number 1520708485 is "5AA42B85". The first four digits match, but the rest doesn't? This is very interesting, though, because (HEX) 2B85 = (Decimal) 11141! Thus it seems the internal number in the EXIF information is a combination of hex and decimal digits! A four digit hex number (in my case "5AA4") followed by the decimal equivalent of the rest of the hex form of the entire serial number (in my case 11141 which is the decimal equivalent of 2B85)!

The Value for my 7D and 5D II work exactly the same way. If I convert the camera's serial number to Hex, then convert the last four hex digits back to decimal, I get the same value that the maker notes show for the camera serial number: The first four digits of the 8-digit hex number followed by the decimal equivalent of the last four digits of the 8-digit hex number.

Although it doesn't help your situation, the best practice when selling a lens anywhere near the value of an **EF 85mm f/1.2 L** would be to document the serial number of the lens and the condition it is in before you ship it.

Comment: It looks as if things are far more complex than I assumed from the appearance of the code.  +1 for the detailed research.

Comment: This is a very informative answer. Thanks on the explanation. In my case, LensSerialnumber matched from 1 shot this summer to one taken last Friday. Same lens different bodies. Upon trying a 5DMIII and another 85mm lens, a different serial number showed up.

Comment: The behavior seems to be body specific with regard to lens ID in the EXIF info. The same cameras that can differentiate between two of the same model lens for AFMA purposes appear to be the ones that accurately report the "Lens Serial Number" in the 'Maker Notes'. But the internal number may not be the same as the number stamped on the lens.

Answer (score 4):

This number looks like a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number.  If you put it into a convertor such as [this one](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) it will give you a decimal number - in this case 134960.  The conversion may or may not be as simple as this but this does give a 6 digit number.

Comment: Not necessarily. 'Hex' IDs reported by Canon components are sometimes a blend of a hex and a decimal number combined to look like one number.

Comment: I tried this method, and it did not correlate to the lens that I've just tested.

Comment: What body are you using?

Comment: This was with a 5Dm3. Converting it to HEX did not yield a matching number on the lens. However, the same value was shown on another 5Dm3 and the 85mm lens.